# size of a static vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am using a static vector inside a member function and pushing back values into that vector;
but the size of vector is only 1 for three function calls.

I am not sure how to make MVCE for this as in MVCE it is working fine for me too, so the problem is obviously some other part of code.
I just want to know or have an idea under which circumstances would my static vector give me such results.

```
class X
{
    //...
};

template <typename T>
void test(T a)
{
    std::cout<<"Function called \n";
    static std::vector<X> vec;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mx);
    //Doing something else with T
    X obj;
    vec.push_back(obj);
    std::cout<<"no of elements in vec is "<<vec.size()<<"\n";

}
```

The output coming is

```
Function called 
no of elements in vec is 1
Function called 
no of elements in vec is 1
Function called 
no of elements in vec is 1
```

The member function is called from the CPPREST http_client request call.

Comment: Did you call `test()` 3 times with different type `T`?

Comment: yes. but the instance of class under which test is same.

Comment: Then there're 3 different `test()` with 3 instances of `vec` which are irrelevant.

Comment: got it.. thanks a lot. i did not know that. I thought as there is only one instance of class there should be one vector. thanks a lot.

Comment: @songyuanyao you can mention the same in answer , so that i can accept it as correct answer. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the template instantiations with different type are irrelevant. It means if you called `test()` three time with different type `T`, then three irrelevant `test()` will be instantiated, with 3 diffrent instances of `vec`. That's why you're getting the result that their size are all `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Your request call probably looks similar to this
    int i = 1;
    float f = 2.5;
    char c = 'A';
    test(i);
    test(f);
    test(c);

If you add
    test(i);

Then vec.size() for test(int) will be 2
While vec.size() for test(float) and test(char) will stay 1.

You can read more about the behavior of static variables in templates here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/templates-and-static-variables-in-c/

Comment: yeah, i understand now. Thanks for the link.